# How can I update state to include a new manually entered property

Tags: reactjs, object, properties, state

I had state which looked like this

```
 const [tracker, setTracker] = useState([
   {num:0,id:0,name:""}
 ,{num:0,id:1,name:""}
 ,{num:0,id:2,name:""}
 ,{num:0,id:3,name:""}
 ,{num:0,id:4,name:""}
 ,{num:0,id:5,name:""}])
```

I changed it to this

```
   const [tracker, setTracker] = useState([
    {num:0,id:0,name:"", weekTotal:0}
 ,{num:0,id:1,name:"",weekTotal:0}
 ,{num:0,id:2,name:"",weekTotal:0}
 ,{num:0,id:3,name:"",weekTotal:0}
 ,{num:0,id:4,name:"",weekTotal:0}
 ,{num:0,id:5,name:"",weekTotal:0}])
```

Problem is it is not changing in my site. I tried restarting, clearing cache but it is still not showing the property weekTotal in the state. I have the state saved in local storage but it doesn't seem to be registering weekTotal even after a re-render. (it does not show up and is not showing it in the dev tools)

the state  is being passed to a component

Answer (score 0):

Deleted local Storage in browser, restarted and worked